# Windows Phone NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry method missing?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to tighten navigation in my WP8 app and I'm having an issue where I want to exit when the user is on the main xaml page (which could be navigated to from many pages within my app). The simplest way about it seemed to let the back button handle exiting, but in order to do this it seems you need to clear the back button's history so that it can exit.

MSDN says to use the NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry method to clear out back entries (and thus allowing the app to close naturally once the user clicks Back again). But I'm not seeing this method! What gives?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

yes your point is correct. you can clear the back entry and exit by the following piece of code.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: The method RemoveBackEntry doesn't show up under NavigationService

Comment: Actually, What you want, When back key is pressed on the MainPage.xaml, the app should exit without any exception. Right ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to terminate the app in Windows Phone 8 (Just remember to save all your program data before calling this ;-))

```
App.Current.Terminate();
```

Comment: Are you sure your project is set for Windows Phone 8? Terminate is only possible in WP8!